# How to return custom taxonomy term in title for archive?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I am building a site with 2 custom taxonomies (`wired-categories`, `wired-types`) assigned to a CPT (`wired`). I want to show the term in the page title when it is brought up using the `taxonomy-wired-categories.php` or `taxonomy-wired-types.php` archive pages.

My `header.php` file has the following conditionals for creating the title tags on pages according to type:

```
<title>
<?php 
 if(is_front_page()): bloginfo('name'); ?> &middot; <?php bloginfo('description');
 elseif(is_home()): single_post_title(); ?> &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');
 elseif(is_archive()): ?>Archive &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');
 elseif(is_category()): single_cat_title(); ?> &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');
 elseif(is_404()): ?>404 &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');
 elseif(is_tag()): single_tag_title(); ?> &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');
 elseif(is_date()): ?>Date Archives &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');
 elseif(is_author()): the_author(); ?> &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');

 elseif(is_tax()): single_term_title(); ?> &middot; <?php bloginfo('name'); //this line should be returning an appropriate page title

 else: ?><?php the_title(); ?> &middot; <?php bloginfo('name');
 endif;
?>
</title>
```

With the above, when I visit e.g. [domain]/wired-category/[term] I am seeing:

"Archive • [site name]"

when I expect to see:

"[term] • [site name]"

In the browser tab. Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `is_archive` is earlier so it doesn't evaluate the others, it's checked from the top down and since `is_archive` is super generic it will be `true` for all archives, categories, tags, dates, etc etc. You need to go from the most specific to the least specific, not the other way around.

Think of it like this:

```php
 if(is_food()): echo 'food';
 elseif(is_meat()): echo 'meat';
 elseif(is_chicken()): echo 'chicken';
 else: ....
 endif;
```

Anything that's food will be true, so it will print `food`. It will only check `is_meat` if it's not food, but since `is_food` is always true when `is_meat` is true, it will never be checked.

Instead this would work better:

```php
 if(is_chicken()): echo 'chicken';
 elseif(is_meat()): echo 'meat';
 elseif(is_food()): echo 'food';
 else: ....
 endif;
```

Always go from the most specific/rare/unique first, and the most generic/general last.

---

Note that it's not ideal to do this in the theme template though, WordPress has hooks and APIs for generating the title tags already, and you should work with this system rather than preventing it from working with hardcoded title tags

Comment: Ooooh thank you! I'll look into the native WP options, but I have found in the past that they generate titles other than what I (or clients) would want, usually. I imagine that's controllable. Will test this ordering approach when I'm back at my desk tomorrow and come back to accept the answer.